# prevent user from jumping to another line with "enter button" in C

Tags: c, printf, scanf, newline

```
  printf(" -----------------------------------\n");
  printf("|   *** E - Liquid Calculator ***   |\n");
  printf(" -----------------------------------\n");
  printf("| Zutaten                           |\n");
  printf(" -----------------------------------\n");
  printf("| Aroma:     %%   Nikotin:     mg/ml |\n");
  printf("| Nikotinshot:     mg/ml            |\n");
  printf("| In total:      ml                 |\n");
  printf(" -----------------------------------\n");
  printf("| Ergebnis                          |\n");
  printf(" -----------------------------------\n");
  printf("| Aroma:      ml   Nikotin:     ml  |\n");
  printf("| Base:       ml                    |\n");
  printf(" -----------------------------------\n");
```

ive created a little project, where i want the user to enter 4 values in a table, and then calculate the ingredients. however, if the user presses "enter" before actually entering a value, the cursor will just jump into a new line and then destroy the layout of the whole programm.

ive tried the following code to prevent any unexpected "newlines / enter"

```
do   
  {
    POSITION (6,10);
    scanf("%c", &spacebar);
    if (spacebar == '\n')
    {
      POSITION (18,0);
      printf("Eingabe erfordelich!\n");
    }
  } while (spacebar == '\n');
  clearBuffer();
```

the problem with this is, that once i actually enter a value, the programm skips the entered value and i need to actually enter it a second time, before it gets stored in the variable.

this is how it looks like altogether, the "prevent newline" function and the first function to read the users input for "aroma"

```
  do   //prevent the user from pressing enter before actually typing a number
  {
    POSITION (6,10);
    scanf("%c", &spacebar);
    if (spacebar == '\n')
    {
      POSITION (18,0);
      printf("Eingabe erfordelich!\n");
    }
  } while (spacebar == '\n');
  clearBuffer();
  POSITION (18,0);
  CLEAR_LINE;


  do
  {
    POSITION (6,10);
    Scan_Erg = scanf("%f", &Aroma);
    clearBuffer();
    if (Scan_Erg == 0)
    {
      POSITION (16,0);
      FORECOLOR_RED;
      printf("Please only enter numbers!");
      FORECOLOR_YELLOW;
      POSITION (6,14);
      CLEAR_LINE;
      POSITION (6,10);
      printf("    %%   Nikotin:     mg/ml |");
    }
    else
    {
      POSITION (6,10);
      CLEAR_LINE;
      POSITION (6,10);
      printf("%4.1f%%   Nikotin:     mg/ml |", Aroma);
    }
  } while (Scan_Erg == 0);
```

Does anyone have an idea, how to block the input from being just a newline, when theres no value being entered? 
any suggestions or help would be appreciated. 
i am new to programming :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do more than most simple input/output via `scanf()` and `printf()`.

You could build your own system for reading user input.

But as you suspect, this problem is not new, and some clever people provide a broadly used solution: the `curses` library.

Depending on your development and/or target system you might like to search for `ncurses` or `pdcurses` and its documentation. There will be some tutorials, too.